# Query repository file contents from GitLab

Tags: sql, gitlab, invantive-sql

I want retrieve the commit id of a file `readmeTest.txt` through Invantive SQL like so:

```
select * from repository_files(29, file-path, 'master')
```

But for this to work I need a `project-id`, `file-path` and a `ref`.

I know my `project-id` (I got it from `select * from projects`) and my `ref` (`master` branch) but I don’t know where I can find the path to the file I want to retrieve information of.

So where can I find the value of `file-path` and `ref`?

This is my repository directory tree, where I can see the files exist:

[image: Directory tree]

[image: Directory tree]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join several entities in GitLab to get the information you need.

The fields from your `repository_files` table function and their meaning:

- `project-id` can be found as `id` in the `projects` entity, as you already knew;
- `ref-name` can be found as `name` in `repositories`;
- `ref` is the name of a branch, a tag or a commit, so let's assume you want the `master` for now.

Giving this information, you need the below query to get all repository files and their content in a project (I narrowed it down to a single project for now):

```
select pjt.name project_name
,      rpe.name repository_name
,      rpf.content file
from   projects pjt
join   repositories(pjt.id) rpe
on     1=1
and    rpe.name like '%.%'
join   repository_files(pjt.id, rpe.name, 'master') rpf
on     1=1
where  pjt.id = 1
```

Comment: If i use a project id that doesnt exist i get 3 empty fields like expected but if i use a pjt.id of an existing project i get an exception which says "404 Tree Not Found (gitlaburl.com/api/v3/projects/30/repository/tree)"